# What does “ich will mit him” mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning

I’m a very beginner at German. I’d like to know the meaning of this phrase that Google Translate doesn’t translate clearly for me:

> Was machst du am Wochenende? Ich will mit him Grünen erholen.

In particular, I am confused by  “ich will mit him”.

Comment: *Ich will mit him Grünen erholen* is not a correct German sentence. *Ich will mich im Grünen erholen* **is**.

Comment: I second @adjan's remark and follow up to it by asking where the sentence "Ich will mit him Grünen erholen." originates from. As a wild guess, was it sent from a mobile device that (mis)corrects input based upon a dictionary?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Autumn connection often is the bull's hit.

Comment: And once again: Can you give the origin? Maybe it is _Ich will mich mit ihm im Grünen erholen_?

Comment: @o.r. Mapper and knut, thank you very much for your answers and also for going further to make sure the translation was right,  but I don't have the original text,  I copied it from a group that they write in German,  it's education based, I felt it might be wrong, that's why I asked it here

Answer (score 1):

The translation is:

> What are you going to do in the weekend? I want to relax in the
>   coutryside.

But as adjan already wrote, the correct sentence in German would be: *Ich will mich im Grünen erholen.*

Answer (score 0):

There is two potential answers:

> Ich will mit him Grünen erholen.

Is not a valid sentence. But it can be understood either as:

> Ich will mich mit ihm im Grünen erholen.

(I want to relax with him in the countryside.)

> Ich will mich im Grünen erholen.

(I want to relax in the countryside)

Whereas "im Grünen" means "in the green", meaning "where it is green" or better: outside the city, in rural areas, near big forests or nice fields.